# Excel VBA Run Time Error 1004 When getting data from other worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I cant show the entire code, but this is the piece that is giving me trouble. I have a bunch of sheets that follow a specific naming convention and I want to access specific sheets based on another variable (n). All of the variables have been defined and they are taking on the correct values except when the code gets to the Density variable I get the Run-time error 1004. In the case below, the sheet name is M1, which corresponds to the Mixture variable.

```
n = 1
Mixture = "M" + n
Density(1, 1) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Mixture).Cells(Row, Column).Value
```

Sam was correct, row and column were the problem.

Comment: what value is `Row` and `Column`? I bet that one or both of them is set to 0.

Comment: try `Mixture="M" & n` with & as the concatenating chain

Comment: Sam you are spot on, thank a lot.

Comment: Nutsch from what I could tell both ways + an & work the same way. But Sam was correct. Thank you for the help.